# Error Provider para un DateTimePicker y un Textbox

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms, datetimepicker, textbox

Estoy realizando una app en windows forms donde hago registros, pero validarme que algunos campos sean llenados estoy usando Error Provider, mas sin embargo cuando provoco el error me marcan todos excepto el DateTimePicker y un Textbox donde debo ingresar Int que error puede tener mi codigo?

```
 private void btnCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Metodo para limpiar los error provider(si anteriormente ya hubieran aparecido)
        LimpiarErrorICono();
        if (txtSalesOrderI.Text == string.Empty || txtModelo.Text == string.Empty || txtCustomer.Text == string.Empty || txtTotalI.Text == string.Empty || cmbPriorityI.Text == string.Empty
            || cmbPriorityStatus.Text == string.Empty || dtmpDateReceived.Checked)  
        {
            this.MensajeError("Faltan Ingresar Datos");

            if (txtSalesOrderI.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(txtSalesOrderI, "Ingrese un SalesOrder");
            }

            if (txtCustomer.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(txtCustomer, "Ingrese un Customer");
            }

            if(txtModelo.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(txtModelo, "Ingrese un Modelo");
            }

            //En este campo es el text box que debe ir un int y no me aparece el error provider cuando no ingreso nada
            if(txtTotalI.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(txtTotalI, "Ingrese un Numero");
            }

            if(cmbPriorityI.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(cmbPriorityI, "Ingrese una Prioridad");
            }

            if (cmbPriorityStatus.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(cmbPriorityStatus, "Ingrese una Estatus");
            }

            //DateTimePicker en el cual debo checar una fecha y si no deberia aparecer el error icon
            if (dtmpDateReceived.Checked == false)
            {
                ErrorIcono.SetError(dtmpDateReceived, "Ingrese una Fecha");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el código siguiente no hay error sintactico:

```
  //DateTimePicker en el cual debo checar una fecha y si no deberia aparecer el error icon
   if (dtmpDateReceived.Checked == false)
   {
     ErrorIcono.SetError(dtmpDateReceived, "Ingrese una Fecha");
   }
```

El error radica en que la propiedad `dtmpDateReceived.Checked` no es lo apropiado para detectar tu error, si el `Error Provider` no marca el error en el `DateTimePicker` es por que la condición `dtmpDateReceived.Checked == false` no se cumple, sencillamente por que `dtmpDateReceived.Checked` está establecida a `true`, `dtmpDateReceived.Checked` de manera predeterminada es `true` y solo cambia si la propiedad `ShowCheckBox` del `DateTimePicker` está establecida a `true` y es el usuario quien puede establecerla a `false` desmarcando el `CheckBox`.
Si tu objetivo es validar la fecha colocada, debes emplear una condición adecuada al error que deseas evitar, por ejemplo:

```
if(dtmpDateReceived.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
{
  ErrorIcono.SetError(dtmpDateReceived, "La Fecha coincide con la fecha actual");
}
```

Te serviría para impedir que el usuario colocará la fecha actual, si el caso es que deseas cualquier fecha menos la del día actual.

Answer (score 1):

podría probar con esto:

```
   //En este campo es el text box que debe ir un int y no me aparece el error provider cuando no ingreso nada
        if(txtTotalI.Text == "")
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(txtTotalI, "Ingrese un Numero");
        }
//DateTimePicker en el cual debo checar una fecha y si no deberia aparecer el error icon
        if (dtmpDateReceived.Checked = false)
        {
            ErrorIcono.SetError(dtmpDateReceived, "Ingrese una Fecha");
        }
```

No es necesario usar un string.empty, puedes preguntar si es vacio ""

Comment: No me funciono tampoco como me dijiste

Answer (score 1):

Para tu verificación puedes realizar lo siguiente, en ves de hacer un if() en general y después ir verificando uno a uno para mostrar el error, copia, remplaza los datos y pega el siguiente código las veces que sea necesario.

> Strings:

```
If (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Campo.Text))
{
ErrorIcono.SetError(txtCustomer, "Ingrese....");
return;
}
```

> Ints:

```
If (int.Parse(Campo.Text) >= 0)
{
ErrorIcono.SetError(txtCustomer, "Ingrese....");
return;
}
```

> DateTimePickers:

```
If(Campo.Value == DateTime.UtcNow.Date)
{
ErrorIcono.SetError(txtCustomer, "Ingrese....");
return;
}
```